# something wrong with my c++ code

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

I wrote a program for testing purposes related to my work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
/* Function to convert an std::string to int*/
int UsingATOI(std::string &str)
{
  std::string strIntString(str);
  int iConvertToMe;
  iConvertToMe = atoi( strIntString.c_str());
  return iConvertToMe;

}

/*function to splt an std::string using a delimiter ,
here a vector is exclusively passed an an argument*/

std::vector<std::string> &split(const std::string &s, char delim, std::vector<std::string> &elems) 
{
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string item;
    while(std::getline(ss, item, delim)) 
    {
        elems.push_back(item);
    }
    return elems;
}

/*function to splt an std::string using a delimiter ,
here a vector is prepared inside the function and returned*/
std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &s, char delim) 
{
    std::vector<std::string> elems;
    return split(s, delim, elems);
}

int showrecord(vector<std::string> all_lines,int linenumber)
{
      char *a[]={"O_BILLABLE_ACCOUNT","O_CUSTOMER_TYPE_INDICATOR","O_A_PARTY_MSISDN_ID","O_A_PARTY_EQUIPMENT_NUMBER","O_A_PARTY_IMSI","O_A_PARTY_LOCATION_INFO_CELL_ID","O_B_PARTY_MSISDN_ID","O_B_PARTY_EQUIPMENT_NUMBER","O_B_PARTY_IMSI","O_B_PARTY_LOCATION_INFO_CELL_ID","O_APN","O_URL_ADDRESS","O_IP_ADDRESS","O_DIALLED_DIGITS","O_CALL_ESTABLISHMENT_REASON","O_TERMINATION_REASON","O_COMPENSATION_CODE","O_CALL_DIRECTION_CODE","O_EVENT_TYPE","O_EVENT_SUB_TYPE","O_SUPPLEMENTARY_SERVICE","O_CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT_INFORMATION","O_CHARGING_ID","O_PROVIDER_ID","O_ZONE_INDICATOR","O_ROUTING_PREFIX","O_SERVICE_CODE","O_NETWORK","O_ORIGINAL_FILE_NAME","O_MSC_IDENTIFIER","O_CIRCUIT_TRUNK_IDENTIFIERS","O_CALL_SOURCE_TYPE","O_CALL_START_TIMESTAMP","O_CALL_END_TIME","O_UNIT_OF_MEASURE","O_DURATION","O_VOLUME","O_UPLINK_DOWNLINK","O_MESSAGE_SIZE_VIDEO","O_GROSS_CHARGE","O_NET_CHARGE","O_CURRENCY","O_QOS_REQUESTED_RECEIVED","O_INBOUND_ROAMING_INDICATOR","O_OUTBOUND_MSRN","O_CONTENT_TYPE","O_CONTENT_PROVIDER_ID","O_CONTENT_ID","O_CONTENT_DESCRIPTION","O_TON_NPI_CALLING_CALLED","O_IN_GW_GSM_VPN_EVENT_INFO","O_IN_GW_CALL_TYPE","O_IN_GW_TERMINATION_TYPE","O_IN_GW_BUSINESS_GROUP","O_IN_GW_TRANSMISSION_TYPE","O_IN_GW_BUSINESS_PERSONAL_CALL","IN_PRE_INFO","O_CAMEL_SERVICE_KEY","O_CAMEL_SERVICE_LEVEL","O_CAMEL_SERVICE_USED","O_CAMEL_CALL_REFERENCE","O_CAMEL_MSC_ADDRESS","O_CAMEL_DESTINATION_NUMBER","O_ROAMING_TYPE","O_CAMEL_SCP_ADDRESS","O_CALL_REFERENCE","O_CALL_NUMBERS","O_SMS_SERVICECENTREADDRESS","O_VARCHAR_3","O_INPUT_RECORD_TYPE","O_VARCHAR_5","O_VARCHAR_6","O_VARCHAR_7","O_VARCHAR_8","O_VARCHAR_9"};
      vector<std::string> fields(a,a+75);
      vector<std::string> linesplit=split(all_lines[linenumber-1],',');
      vector<std::string>::const_iterator itrecord=linesplit.begin();
      vector<std::string>::const_iterator it=fields.begin();
      int counter=1;
      for(;it!=fields.end()||itrecord!=linesplit.end();counter++,++it,++itrecord)
      {
      cout << counter <<"\t"<<*it<<" "<<*itrecord<<endl;
      }
      return 0;
}

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{

       vector<std::string> lines;
       lines.reserve(5000);
       /*getting the file name*/
       string filename(argv[1]);
       ifstream file;
       file.open(filename.c_str());
       if(!file.is_open())
       {
              cerr<<"Error opening file : "<<filename.c_str()<<endl;
              return -1;
       }
      /*Read the lines and store it in the vector*/
      string line;
      while(getline(file,line))
      {
          lines.push_back(line);
      }
      file.close();
      vector<std::string> lines_in_file=split(argv[2],',');
      string detail_record("-show");

if(!detail_record.compare(*(lines_in_file.begin())))
{
        int linetoshow=UsingATOI(*(++lines_in_file.begin()));
        showrecord(lines,linetoshow);

}
getch();      
}
```

This is the contents of the input file:

```
,2,353867835022;11,012268004278220,272023112983396,272-02f-20008-26217,3538353588202;11,,,,,,,08353588202b,3,00,,O,V,VOICE,,,11162812,,,17683,11,HPLMN,M10MSS_TTFILE_0650_20110414204840,M10MSS,W20B13I;0VMSGRI,1,20110414204447,204517,1,30,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,353868001810,,,,06631f000a,1:353860295822::::08353588202b::3538353588202,,,MOC,,,,1,
,2,353867835022;11,012268004278220,272023112983396,272-02f-20008-26217,3538557137704;11,,,,,,,08557137704b,3,00,,O,V,VOICE,,,11162812,,,17687,11,HPLMN,M10MSS_TTFILE_0650_20110414204840,M10MSS,W20B13I;0VMSGRI,1,20110414204447,204517,1,30,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,353868001810,,,,06631f000a,1:353860295822::::08557137704b::3538557137704,,,MOC,,,,,
,0,353867835022;11,,272023201187741,,353854100352;11,,,,,,,,3,04,,O,V,IPVMS,SS04,,971062,,,17685,,HPLMN,M30MSS_TTFILE_0511_20110606165900,M30MSS,W30EABI;0VMSGRI,,20110606185900,170900,1,600,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,00000014,Basic,,fdc45c001e,353868001830,353868001241,,353868001241,fdc45c001e,,,,,,,,,
,0,353867835022;11,,272023201187741,,353894201740;11,,,,,,,,3,04,,O,V,IPVMS,SS04,,971062,,,17684,,HPLMN,M30MSS_TTFILE_0511_20110606180901,M30MSS,W30EABI;0VMSGRI,,20110606180901,171901,1,600,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,00000014,Basic,,fdc45c001e,353868001830,353868001241,,353868001241,fdc45c001e,,,,,,,,,
,0,353867835022;11,,272023201187741,,353833588202;11,,,,,,,,3,04,,O,V,IPVMS,SS04,,971062,,,17683,,HPLMN,M30MSS_TTFILE_0511_20110606181902,M30MSS,W30EABI;0VMSGRI,,20110606181902,172902,1,600,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,00000014,Basic,,fdc45c001e,353868001830,353868001241,,353868001241,fdc45c001e,,,,,,,,,
,0,353867835022;11,,272023201187741,,353857137704;11,,,,,,,,3,04,,O,V,IPVMS,SS04,,971062,,,17687,,HPLMN,M30MSS_TTFILE_0511_20110606182903,M30MSS,W30EABI;0VMSGRI,,20110606182903,173903,1,600,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,00000014,Basic,,fdc45c001e,353868001830,353868001241,,353868001241,fdc45c001e,,,,,,,,,
,2,353868898655;11,354346049187430,272023112144539,272-02f-20008-24049,353894414476;11,,,,,,,353894414476,3,00,,O,V,VOICE,,,12649734,,,17684,11,HPLMN,M10MSS_TTFILE_6518_20110513104240,M10MSS,W20B13I;0GRI3,1,20110513104023,104130,1,67,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,353868001810,,,,c6d299000a,1:353868898655::::353894414476::353894414476,,,,,,,,
,2,353872458299;11,358005031789960,272023112578235,272-02f-20025-15107,353876225788;11,,,,,,,353876225788,3,00,,O,V,VOICE,,,12664989,,,17683,11,HPLMN,M10MSS_TTFILE_6518_20110513104240,M10MSS,W20B03I;0GRI3,1,20110513104209,104226,1,17,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,353868001810,,,,c7266e000a,1:353872458299::::353876225788::353876225788,,,,,,,,
,2,353872889489;11,354866045620160,272023112067271,272-02f-31011-11492,353863475401;11,,,,,,,0863475401,3,00,,O,V,VOICE,,,12668430,,,17685,11,HPLMN,M10MSS_TTFILE_6518_20110513104240,M10MSS,BLRC11I;0GRI3,2,20110513104213,104237,1,24,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,353868001810,,,,c725a9000a,1:353872889489::::0863475401::353863475401,,,,,,,,
,2,353872889489;11,354866045620160,272023112067271,272-02f-31011-11492,353863475401;11,,,,,,,0863475401,3,00,,O,V,VOICE,,,12668430,,,17687,11,HPLMN,M10MSS_TTFILE_6518_20110513104240,M10MSS,BLRC11I;0GRI3,2,20110513104213,104237,1,24,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,353868001810,,,,c725a9000a,1:353872889489::::0863475401::353863475401,,,,,,,,
,2,353867835022;11,353681041426390,272023201187741,272-02f-20017-06609,353854100351;11,,,,,,,0854100351,3,00,,O,D,DATA,,,7124395,,,17683,16,HPLMN,M20MSS_TTFILE_8377_20110605170245,M20MSS,W30B22I;0GRI3,1,20110605130014,170054,1,41,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,353868001820,,,,b60a5c0014,1:353867835022::::0854100351::353854100351,,,,,,,,
,2,353867835022;11,353681041426390,272023201187741,272-02f-20017-06609,353854100353;11,,,,,,,0854100353,3,00,,O,D,DATA,,,7124395,,,17687,16,HPLMN,M20MSS_TTFILE_8377_20110605170245,M20MSS,W30B22I;0GRI3,1,20110605130014,170054,1,41,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,353868001820,,,,b60a5c0014,1:353867835022::::0854100353::353854100353,,,,,,,,
,2,353867835022;11,353681041426390,272023201187741,272-02f-20017-06609,353894201740;11,,,,,,,0894201740,3,00,,O,D,DATA,,,7124395,,,17684,16,HPLMN,M20MSS_TTFILE_8377_20110605170245,M20MSS,W30B22I;0GRI3,1,20110605140015,170054,1,41,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,353868001820,,,,b60a5c0014,1:353867835022::::0894201740::353894201740,,,,,,,,
,2,353830020353;11,353681041426390,272023201580328,272-02f-20017-06609,353854100352;11,,,,,,,0854100352,3,00,,O,D,DATA,,,7124395,,,17685,16,HPLMN,M20MSS_TTFILE_8377_20110605170245,M20MSS,W30B22I;0GRI3,1,20110605130015,170054,1,41,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,353868001820,,,,b60a5c0014,1:353830020353::::0854100352::353854100352,,,,,,,,
```

Each line is guaranteed to have 75 fields (meaning 74 commas). There are no compiler errors. I run the program like this:

```
a.out text_file.txt -show,1
```

The program crashes with a segmentation fault after printing the last field. What's wrong with the code? I think the problem is the fact is that even though the line has 75 fields, if the last field is empty, then the next character after the last comma is newline. But in real time I cannot change the input data files but I need to handle this in the code itself if the last field is not present. I did manually add a random number after the 74th comma, then the code works fine without a seg fault.

Comment: why not use vectors everywhere, instead of pointers to char arrays?

Comment: Why are you using a vector to store what looks like a constant static array of character strings ? I have trouble understanding which constructor is called when you try to initialize the fields variable.

Comment: you should also check itrecord != linesplit.end() in your for loop

Comment: What is the "split" function?  It's not defined.

Comment: @James Kanze: the for condition uses && not || because both iterators must be valid.

Comment: @sirdarius...the fields vector will be initialized with the contents of the array which later on i will use for printing.that is just for ease.But that is not the issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not at all clear what you're trying to do, but two things stick
out:

- You're reconstructiong the `fields` vector every time you enter the function, although you never modify it.  I'ld also drop the `75`:

```
    static char const* a[] = { ... };
    static std::vector fields(  begin( a ), end( a ) );
```

- You're iterating over the number of `fields`.  What happens if a line
  doesn't contain that many fields?  The end condition should be `it !=
  fields.end() && itrecord != linesplit.end()`.  Or you add some earlier
  logic to ensure that there are enough fields.
- You're algorithm for `split` is incorrect.  I've seen this proposed
  several times, but using `getline` is *not* an appropriate solution;
  it fails if it extracts no characters (including no delimiter).  You
  could make it work by systematically postfixing a delimiter; i.e.
  `std::istringstream ss(s + ' ')` as the first line in `split`, but I
  still find it misleading, and would prefer something more along the
  lines of:

```
    std::vector
    split( std::string const& source, char delim )
    {
        std::vector results;
        std::string::const_iterator curr = source.begin();
        std::string::const_iterator end = source.end();
        std::string::const_iterator next = std::find( curr, end, delim );
        while ( next != end ) {
            results += std::string( curr, next );
            curr = next + 1;
            next = std::find( curr, end, delim );
        }
        results += std::string( curr, next );
        return results;
    }
```

One thing which makes me curious: your invocation (`a.out ...`) is
clearly Unix, but the code as you post it won't compile under Unix
(`<conio.h>` and `getch`).  So just what platform are you using?

Comment: this function will be called only once.Not many times!The line is guaranteed to have 75 fields.

Comment: @Rahul "The line is guaranteed to have 75 fields": how and by whom?  If it's external input, there is no guarantee.

Comment: @Rahul Very.  Given a compilable example, it was easy to find where the real error was, and I've updated my answer to reflect it.  (In your place, however, I'd still add some error checking code, in case you get fed the wrong file.)

Comment: @james...Thank you very much for ur inputs.I did not add the error checking code since i wanted to test the actual functionality first and keep the minimum code possible at present.ans the function u suggested is very good.thanks a lot for that.I donno why a -1 for this question which i think is a genuine question.